# How to use the sharp library to resize a Parse file img?

Tags: parse-server

I have a Parse Cloud `afterSave` trigger from where I can access the obj and inside the obj a field that has a store parse file img.

I want to use sharp to resize it and save it in another field but I'm struggling and getting an error when I use sharp. Here is a summary of the code I already have inside the cloud trigger:

```
let file = obj.get("photo");

        sharp(file)
            .resize(250, 250)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("img-----", data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("--Error--", err);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I managed to figure out how to create Parse Cloud afterSave trigger which resizes and then saves the img, I couldn't find much information on it so ill post my solution so others can use it if it's helpful.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Landmarks", async (req) => {
    const obj = req.object;
    const objOriginal = req.original;

    const file = obj.get("photo");
    const condition = file && !file.equals(objOriginal.get("photo"));

    if (condition) {

        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: file.url() })
            .then((res) => {

                sharp(res.buffer)
                    .resize(250, 250, {
                        fit: "fill",
                    })
                    .toBuffer()
                    .then(async (dataBuffer) => {
                        const data = { base64: dataBuffer.toString("base64") };

                        const parseFile = new Parse.File(
                            "photo_thumbnail",
                            data
                        );
                        await parseFile.save();
                        await obj.save({ photo_thumb: parseFile });
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log("--Sharp-Error--", err);
                    });

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("--HTTP-Request-Error--", err);
            });

    } else {
        console.log("--Photo was deleted or did not change--");
    }
});
```

So to break this down a bit, what i did first was get the `obj` and the `objOriginal` so i can compare them and check for a change in a specific field. This condition is necessery since in my case i wanted to save the resized img in parse which would cause an infinite loop otherwise.

After that i did a `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: file.url()}).then()` which is the way i found to get the buffer from the `photo`. The buffer is stored inside `res.buffer` and we need it for sharp.

Next i use `sharp(res.buffer)` since sharp also accepts buffers and resize it to the desired dimensions (i used the fit config for it). Then we turn the resulted img into another buffer using `.toBuffer()`. Furthermore, i use a `.then().catch()` blocks and if sharp is succesful i turned the outputed buffer into a base64 and passed it in `Parse.File()`, note that the specific syntax `{ base64: 'insert buffer here' }` is important.

And finally i just save the file and the obj. Is this the best way to do it, absolytely not, but its the one i found that works. Another possible solution is instead of using `buffers` and `base64` is to create a temporary dir which you save the images there, use them and then delete the directory. I tried this as well but had issues making it work.